# How to add data to firebase using angular.I have fetched the data from the firestore but can't able to post the data

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm creating the angular web application.I want to use the Firebase as the database for my project.First I can't able to fetch the data from it. Now however i have managed to fetched it from the fire base. now i can't able to add the data to Firebase. help me to find the solution for this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2dlP.png)

How to add data to Firebase using angular.I have fetched the data from the firestore but can't able to post the data.I have provided my code in the above image.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: Did you see the AngularFire documentation on writing data to Firestore: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore.md#writing-data?

Comment: yeah i tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: None of the code you shared shows any call to write to Firestore like the ones in the link I shared. Please update your question to show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (as formatted text, rather than a screenshot).